# Como retirar mesas iguais

Tags: php, html, css

Gostaria saber se conseguem me ajudar a eliminar as mesas repetidas, sendo que todas elas estão ocupadas e mesmo assim aparecem a verde.

Cada mesa que eu ocupo aparece mais uma de cada, ou seja, se apenas tiver uma mesa ocupada, aparece uma mesa 1 a vermelho e uma mesa de cada, 2, 3 e 4 a verde.

Se ocupar duas mesas aparecem 2 mesas um, uma a verde outra a vermelho, igualmente para a mesa 2 e a mesa 3 e 4 aparecem 2 de cada a verde.
Não estou a entender o que terei mal.

```
.button {
    background-color:#60b0df;
    width:157px;
    height:95px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    float:left;
}

.button1 {
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    float:left;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style:solid;
}

.button2 {
    margin-top:0px;
}

.button3 {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.button4 {
    height:100%;
    margin-left:10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:5px;
    position:relative;
    border-right: 4px solid;
}

.button5 {
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.button6{
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.bt5 {
    background-color:#60b0df;
    width:157px;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    float:left;
}

.bt6 {
    background-color:#60b0df;
    width:70px;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    float: left;
}

.botao1 {
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image: url('open.png');
}

.botao2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    background-image: url('trocar.png');
    width:30px;
    height:30px; 
    float:right; 
    margin-bottom:15px;
    right:5px;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.botao3 {
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image: url('save.png');
}

.botao4 {
    width:30px;
    height:30px; 
    float: right; 
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 5px; 
    bottom: 5px;
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image: url('exit.png');
}

.botao5 {
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image: url('incluirComanda.png');
}

.fonts {
    font:19px arial, sans-serif;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.font {
    font:12px arial, sans-serif;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.linha {
    background-color:#60b0df;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:35px;
    float:left; 
}

.linhafont {
    font:15px arial, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:left;
}

.login {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.centrar {
    text-align: center ;
}

.centrar2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.logo1 {
    margin-top:5px;
}

.conexao {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.total {
    margin-bottom:19px;
}

.total1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    padding: 4px;
}

.cabecalho {
    width:100%
}

.opcao1 {
    float:left;
    color:#87CEFA;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.mesas {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:10px;
}

<?php
    include"first_connect.php";
    $id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/erbonlogo.png"/>
        <?php
            if($id == 6) {
        ?>
                <title>Banquetes</title>
        <?php
            }

            if($id == 2) {
        ?>
                <title>Bar</title>
        <?php
            }

            if($id == 3) {
        ?>
                <title>Frigobar</title>
        <?php
            }

            if($id == 1) {
        ?>
                <title>Restaurante</title>
        <?php
            }

            if($id == 5) {
        ?>
                <title>Room Service</title>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </head>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT Ac.id AS IdPointOfSaleAccount, 
            P.id AS IdPointOfSale, P.[pointOfSale] AS PointOfSaleDescription, 
            Ac.number AS Number, Ac.total AS TotalValue, Ac.isClosed AS IsClosed, Ac.isActive AS IsActive, 
            T.id AS IdTable, T.tableDescription AS TableDescription, Ac.comments AS Comments, 
            AcDetail.id AS IdDetails, AcDetail.quantity AS QuantityDetail, AcDetail.valueTotal AS ValueTotalDetails, 
            AcDetail.isActive AS IsActiveDetail, AcDetail.updatedBy AS UpdateLine, 
            S.id AS Id, S.[description] AS [Description], S.idServiceAccounts AS IdServiceAccount, 
            SR.idServiceDepartments AS IdDepartment, (CASE WHEN SR.priceSale = 0 OR SR.priceSale is null 
            THEN S.priceSale ELSE SR.priceSale END) AS Price, 
            S.icms AS Tax6, S.iss AS Tax1, S.ir AS Tax2, S.csll AS Tax3, S.pis AS Tax4, S.cofins AS Tax5, 
            S.isProductKitchen AS IsProductKitchen, S.isServiceTax AS IsServiceTax, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1 AS PrinterKitchen1, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen1Font, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2 AS PrinterKitchen2, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen2Font, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3 AS PrinterKitchen3, 
            PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen3Font 
            FROM PointOfSaleAccount Ac 
            INNER JOIN PointOfSaleAccountDetails AcDetail ON Ac.id = AcDetail.idPointOfSaleaccount 
            AND AcDetail.isActive = 1 INNER JOIN Services S ON AcDetail.idService = S.id 
            LEFT JOIN ServicesPointOfSalePrinterKitchen Printer  
            ON S.id = Printer.idProduct AND Printer.isActive = 1 AND Printer.idPointOfSale = $id 
            LEFT JOIN ServicesPrinterKitchen PrinterConfig ON Printer.idServicesPrinterKitchen = PrinterConfig.id 
            INNER JOIN ServicesDepartmentsRelationship SR ON S.id = SR.idServices AND SR.isActive = 1 
            AND SR.idServiceDepartments = (SELECT P2.idDepartment FROM PointOfSale P2 WHERE P2.id = Ac.idPointOfSale) 
            INNER JOIN PointOfSale P ON Ac.idPointOfSale = P.id LEFT JOIN PointOfSalesTables T 
            ON Ac.idPointOfSaleTable = T.id 
            WHERE Ac.isClosed = 0 AND Ac.isActive = 1 AND Ac.idPointOfSale = $id 
            ORDER BY Ac.number";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    $sql1 = "SELECT P.id AS Id, P.pointOfSale AS [Description], P.printerExtrat1 AS PrinterExtrat1, 
             P.printerExtrat1FonteTicket AS PrinterExtrat1Font, 
             P.printerExtrat2 AS PrinterExtrat2, P.printerExtrat2FonteTicket AS PrinterExtrat2Font, 
             P.printerExtrat3 AS PrinterExtrat3, P.printerExtrat3FonteTicket AS PrinterExtrat3Font, 
             T.id AS IdTable, T.tableDescription AS TableDescription FROM PointOfSale P 
             LEFT JOIN PointOfSalesTables T ON P.id = T.idPointOfSale AND T.isActive = 1 
             WHERE P.isActive = 1 ORDER BY P.pointOfSale";

    $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);

?>
    <form action="" method="post">  
        <div class="button2">
            <input type="image" src="image/trocarPDV.png" value="Trocar" name="TrocarPDV">
        </div>
        <span class="linha linhafont">
<?php
            if($id == 6) {
                echo "BANQUETES";
            }

            if($id == 2) {
                echo "BAR";
            }

            if($id == 3) {
                echo "FRIGOBAR";
            }

            if($id == 1) {
                echo "RESTAURANTE";
            }

            if($id == 5) {
                echo "ROOM SERVICE";
            }
?>
        </span>
        <div class="button7">
            <input style="float:left" type="image" src="image/incluirComanda.png" value="Incluir" name="IncluirComanda">

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["TrocarPDV"])) {
        header("Location: pag2.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST["IncluirComanda"])) {
        header("Location: banquetes.php?id=$id");
    }

    $row[0] = "";
    $i = 0;
    $conf = 0;
    $row12[0] = "";
    $i1 = 0;
    $conf1 = 0;
    $nrow = 0;

    while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
            if($row[$j] == $row1[3]) { 
                $conf = 1;
            }

            else {
            }
        }

        if($conf == 1) { 
            $conf = 0;
        }

        else {
            $resultado3 = $row1[8];

            if($id == 2 || $id == 1) {
                if($resultado3 == "") {
                    $resultado1 = $row1[3];
                    $resultado2 = $row1[4];
                    $row[$i] = $row1[3];
?>
    <span class="button fonts"><?php echo $resultado1;echo "</br>";echo $resultado2;?></span>
            </div>
    </form>
<?php
                    $i = $i + 1;
                }

                else {
                    for($j1 = 0; $j1 < $i1; $j1++) {
                        if($row12[$j1] == $resultado3) {
                            $conf1 = 1;
                        }

                        else {
                        }
                    }

                    if($conf1 == 1) {
                        $conf1 = 0;
                    }

                    else {
                        $row12[$i1] = $resultado3;
                        $nrow = $i1;
                        $i1 = $i1 + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                $resultado1 = $row1[3];
                $resultado2 = $row1[4];
                $row[$i] = $row1[3];
?>
    <span class="button fonts"><?php echo $resultado1;echo "</br>";echo $resultado2;?></span>
<?php           
            }
        }
    }

    if($id == 2 || $id == 1) {

?>
        <span class="linha linhafont">MESAS</span>
        <form action="" method="post">  
            <div class="button7">
<?php
        while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
            $mesa = $row2[9];
            $id2 = $row2[0];

            if($id2 == $id) {
                for($s = 0; $s <= $nrow; $s ++) {
                    if($mesa == $row12[$s]) {
?>
                        <div class="mesas">
                        <input style="float:left" type="image" src="img/ocupada.jpg" 
                               value="<?php echo $mesa?>" name="<?php echo $mesa?>" height="100">
                        <p><?php echo $mesa;?>
                        </div>
<?php
                    }

                    else {
?>
                        <div class="mesas">
                        <input style="float:left" type="image" src="img/vazia.jpg" 
                               value=<?php echo $mesa?> name=<?php echo $mesa?> height="100">
                        <p><?php echo $mesa;?>
                        </div>
<?php
                    }
?>
            </div>
        </form>
<?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, bom dia, isole os possíveis causadores deste problema.

1 - Certifique que as consultas realizadas não estão retornando um número maior de registro, isso pode ocorrer por causa de um join mal feito. Para ver os dados, debug com var_dump();

2 - Caso os dados estejam retornando de forma correta, sem que haja mesas repetidas, verifique os laços que estão sendo feitos, se não um laço dentro de outro, olhando seu código me parece que isso não ocorre.

Me parece que o seu problema provavelmente esteja relacionado ao item 1.

Obtendo o resultado do debug, poste para nós!

Comment: Como o faço o debug?

Comment: var_dump($result1); var_dump($result2);

Comment: Resultado:resource(4) of type (SQL Server Statement) resource(5) of type (SQL Server Statement)

Comment: Tente print_r($result1), em vez de var_dump(), ainda não foi o suficiente.

Comment: Resultado: Resource id #4Resource id #5